# How can I create a string of characters of X size when gzipped?

Tags: string, algorithm, gzip

I am trying to create a service call `getBytes(x)` where `x` is the size of the response body in bytes. The problem is that I cannot turn off gzipping of the server response. So I need to figure out how to create a string of characters that has a size of `x` bytes when gzipped. My strings are 1 char = 1 byte. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: Does it need to be exact? If not, what is the error margin?

Comment: Yes, it needs to be exact.

Comment: It can't always be exact.  There will be cases where you are one byte short on the output, but adding one byte to the input adds two bytes to the output.

Comment: Why deal with the compressed response body? That is normally handled internally by HTTP. If also stepping back from that level, then it's easy to get the "correct size" when dealing the the application-level response stream. Also, multiple gzip/deflate implementations/tuning can result in *different* (and equally valid) output for the same input. I would fix the requirement or use an HTTP host that is configurable enough.

Comment: I suspect that there's no way to do this deterministically without digging into the gzip algorithm and understanding it pretty well.  (With other simpler compressions I was able to work this out, but I've never tried it with gzip.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't always get exactly X, but you can get to within a few bytes.  [This code](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/examples/fitblk.c) is one example of how to do it.  It does it with three compression passes, using two decompressions in between.  The decompressions process up to X compressed bytes or a little less than X compressed bytes to see how much uncompressed data to feed on the next compression pass.

Answer (score 1):

Brute force approach would be add 1 random byte to the string, gzip it, measure length until it is x.

To improve it, you can do binary search - double the size of increment you add to string if it is less then needed, or divide over 2 size of increment string to be added if it is too big,  increment string to be appended should be randomly generated at each time.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there could be inputs where either of these algorithms could fail, there's no guarantee you'll cover all output lengths by repeatedly adding random characters to the input.